# Android avd is off-screen

Tags: android, eclipse

When I run my Android app in Eclipse I can see the emulator on the toolbar but the window appears to be off the screen.  Clicking on the icon in the toolbar makes it flash in or out from the right but I cannot see it.

I have had this problem before but I cannot remember how I resolved it.

Comment: Press Alt + Space, select Move, then use the arrow keys to move the window where you can see it.

Answer (score 35):

You could try [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/77361-move-window-keyboard.html).

or

(Windows 7 only)

Hover over the window icon in the task bar so that the preview appears, right click on the preview and select "move."  You should then be able to move the window with the arrow keys.  You may have to hold down the arrow key for what seems to be a very long time.

Comment: Thanks indeed. This saved me ha lot of frustration.

Answer (score 9):

As dell116 said:

> Hover over the window icon in the task bar so that the preview
>   appears, right click on the preview and select "move." You should then
>   be able to move the window with the arrow keys.

But as soon as you have used one of the arrow keys, then move the mouse, and... voilà, the window turns up in front of us, just following the mouse movements. Place the window where you want and click the mouse's left button to release it.

Answer (score 2):

None of the tricks here worked for me. What I had to do was in Windows right click background (desktop) select screen resolution. From there change the resolution to a smaller resolution. The window provided me with the window bar that was cut off, simply drag like normal. After I got it where I got it where I wanted it, I just changed the resolution back.

Answer (score 2):

You can also right click on taskbar->properties change Taskbar location on screen to something else, Apply, and then you can set it back this will put your windows on screen.

Another one is right clicking on the taskbar->Cascade windows - this will put every window together in cascading order which is annoying but it does guarantee all windows will go on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10,I faced the same problem. My solution is like that;

1. Start Android Studio
2. Select the Android Studio from ALT+TAB Menu(If'nothing happens,just relax :) )
3. Now press ALT + Space combination
4. Click Maximize
5. Now you may use the ide :)))

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem. I tried the solutions suggested by Daniel and dell116. At first it did not work as the "Move" option seems to be disabled. However, during my final attempt it worked. I found out that you can only use this method only when the OS is starting up (i.e. when it is showing the android logo).

Good news is that after doing this once, it will stay in the desired position for future runs.